# Extracting values from last axis of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Consider a numpy array `A` of shape `(3,)`. Then the following line

```
x,y,z = A
```

assigns `x` to `A[0]`, `y` to `A[1]` and `z` to `A[2]`. Supoose now that `A` instead has shape `s + (3,)` for some arbitrary shape `s`. I would like to similarly assign `x` to `A[...,0]`, `y` to `A[...,1]` and `z` to `A[...,2]`. The above line

```
x,y,z = A
```

does not work and gives a ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) [when `A` has shape `(2,3)`]. How can I make the desired assignment in a clean way? Obviously the following

```
x,y,z = A[...,0], A[...,1], A[...,2]
```

works but is a bit tedious if 3 is replaced by some large number.

Comment: `x,y,z = [A[...,i] for i in range(3)]`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the suggestion! It appears to be a bit faster actually (2-3 times or so) than the suggestion by mozway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.rollaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html):

```
x, y, z = np.rollaxis(A, -1)
```

Assuming this input:

```
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]])
```

Output:

```
# x, y, z
(array([[0, 3]]), array([[1, 4]]), array([[2, 5]]))
```

This works with any position, just specify the dimension to use as the second parameter of `rollaxis`:

```
x, y, z = np.rollaxis(A, 2)
```

##### timings:

on `shape = (7,6,8,2,1,4,5,9,3) ; A = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)` as input.

```
%timeit x, y, z = np.rollaxis(A, -1)
# 1.96 µs ± 59 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

%timeit x, y, z = np.moveaxis(A, -1, 0)
# 3.78 µs ± 298 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

# credit to @QuangHoang
%timeit x, y, z = [A[...,i] for i in range(3)]
# 691 ns ± 8.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mean np.rollaxis(A,-1) also in the last line? By the way, do you know if there is any significant overhead with this operation? Would the command x,y,z = [A[...,i] for i in range(3)] suggested by Quang Hoang above give any difference in performance?

Comment: The `-1` is equivalent to `2` in this case (last dimension). I didn't time it, this might depend on the size of your data

Comment: Ok, but should it not be np.rollaxis(A, 1) in that case (for the given example)? If I do np.rollaxis(A, 2) I get out of bounds error. Ok, thanks!

Comment: My example has shape `(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: QuangHoang's answer is indeed quite fast

Comment: *NB. `2` is the **third** dimension.*

Comment: Ah sorry, thanks for the clarification! Ok, thanks for checking! Yes, I also timed it and it seems like his suggestion is 2-3 times faster.

Comment: `x,y,z=arr` is essentially `x,y,z=list(arr)` or `x,y,z=[i for i in arr]`.  All involve iterating on the first dimension of `arr`.